# Eigenvalues of a block matrix composed of Toeplitz matrices

Tags: ra.rings-and-algebras, eigenvalues, block-matrices, schur-complement

If I have a block matrix of the form

$$
M = \begin{pmatrix}   
    A &B \\[6pt]
    -B & C
     \end{pmatrix} 
    $$
and if $A$ is invertible I can write determinant in terms of the Schur complement as
$$
det(M) = det(A)det(C+B A^{-1} B)
$$

and as such the characteristic equation is
$$
det(M-\lambda I) = det(A-\lambda I)det(C+B(A-\lambda I)^{-1} B) = 0
$$
If all the blocks are Toeplitz matrices, and non-zero only on and around the primary diagonal, is there some way to get at the eigenvalues of $M$ in terms of the eigenvalues of $A$,$B$, and $C$ without resorting to this characteristic equation?

Essentially I would like to put upper bounds on the max eigenvalue of $M$. I could use the Gershgorin circle theorem directly on $M$, however given that, even though the block components of $M$ are non-zero only near their primary diagonal, this is of course not true of $M$ itself. As such I would expect the circle theorem to put rather poor bounds on it's eigenvalues. I was hoping to get around this by moving instead to look at the block components and applying the circle theorem to *them* instead, as they really will be populated only near their primary diagonals.

Any and all help/comments appreciated.

EDIT: let's assume, if it helps, that all the blocks commute (they will contain only diagonal matrices of constants and derivative operators which I will assume always commute though this depends on the finite difference scheme)

Answer (score 1):

Introduce the projection operator $P$ such that $A=PMP$, $Q=1-P$,  and $C=QMQ$. Next consider the self-energy operator $\Sigma_P(E)=PMQ(E-QMQ)^{-1}QMP$.The map $M\rightarrow PMP+\Sigma_P(E)$ relates the eigenvalue problem on the full space to that on its subspace.

$[M-\lambda I]V=0 \leftrightarrow [PMP+\Sigma_P(\lambda)-\lambda PIP]PV=0$ or equivalently you have to solve the nonlinear eigenvalue problem $[A-B(\lambda-C)^{-1}B-\lambda PIP]PV=0$